# Classic ASP Form Fields

Tags: asp-classic

I have an ASP script with aspcaptcha which has comments form field, and sends an email to the webmaster. However if the visitor does not enter the captcha code correctly, they are taken back to the form page, a message states that they did not fill out the captcha code correctly BUT the form field is blank....
I am wanting to keep the comments in the form field and ask the visitor to re-fill out the captcha code.

Here is the the ASP script:

```
if Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" then
captha = Trim(Request.Form("captha"))
if CheckCAPTCHA(captha) = true then
    ' Process form...CAPTCHA IS VALID!
else
    response.redirect "myform.asp?c=f"
end if
else
response.redirect "myform.asp?v=f"
end if
```

The variable v=f tells the form that the captcha was not filled out, and to throw back an error. How can I populate the form fields with what the visitor already entered without asking them to type their comments all over again?

Comment: This is the exact same problem I am currently running into. Any feedback on the results of this matter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know aspcaptcha but two possabilies:

First, does the form post to itself? That is, is the processing script on the same page as the form? If so then just use `Request.Form("name")`

```
<input name="frmName" type="text" id="frmName" value="<%
    If Request.Form("frmName") <> "" Then Response.Write(Request.Form("frmName"))
%>" />
```

Second, If the form submits to a second page for processing and then returns the user to the original page, use session variables:

```
if CheckCAPTCHA(captha) = true then
    ' Process form...CAPTCHA IS VALID!
else
    Session("frmName") = Request.Form("frmName")
    response.redirect "myform.asp?c=f"
end if
```

Then

```
<input name="frmName" type="text" id="frmName" value="<%
    If Session("frmName") <> "" Then Response.Write(Session("frmName"))
%>" />
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I have a form that posts to itself. The form processing is on the same page as the form itself. My form clears only checkboxes and radio buttons. I was able to find a way to keep the text input entries. Any thoughts? I notice your example (#1) is for text entry. Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A function usually helps in these cases:

Try Something like:

```
'Select between Session Value / Form Value
function SelectValue(sessionValue, frmValue)
    result = ""
    if isnull(frmValue) or frmValue = "" then
        result = sessionValue
    else
        result = frmValue
    end if
    SelectValue = result
end function
```

Your form can then use the function as needed:

**e.g.**

```
<input name="frmName" type="text" id="frmName" value="<% SelectValue(Session("frmName"), Request.Form("frmName"))%>" />
```